# Power Automate-Adobe Sign-Agreement CC

Tags: adobe, powerapps, power-automate, adobe-sign

I have created a power automate flow to create and Adobe Sign Agreement using 'Create an agreement from an uploaded document and send for signature' action.

Now there is a requirement to Specify the copy recipients (CC). Adobe Sign portal and API both has the option to specify CC. However could not find this option in above Power Automate action. How can I specify the CC of the agreement using Power Automate?

Answer (score 0):

If you click on "Show Advanced Options" there is a CC Email option you can add:
[image: CC option in Microsoft Power Automate]